# Objective C iOS UISegmentedControl changing position unexpectedly

Tags: ios, landscape, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a UISegmented control that I need to change the position of whenever the view goes into a landscape view. My code works, but for some very strange reason whenever I try to select the segmented control, it moves back to its portrait position which is off of the screen. This is not happening with buttons that I am using the same method to move them with.

Code:

```
// handle landscape view
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    CGSize size = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size;
    UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [app statusBarOrientation];

    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation)) size = CGSizeMake(size.height, size.width);
    if (!app.statusBarHidden) size.height -= MIN(app.statusBarFrame.size.width, app.statusBarFrame.size.height);

    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation))
    {
        // CGRects of segmented controls
        CGRect modeFrame = [self offAutoHeatCool].frame;
        CGRect fanModeFrame = [self fanMode].frame;

        modeFrame.origin.y = someRelativeInt;
        fanModeFrame.origin.y = someRelativeInt;

        modeFrame.origin.x = someRelativeInt;
        fanModeFrame.origin.x = someRelativeInt;

        [[self modeLabel] setFrame:modeLabelFrame];
        [[self offAutoHeatCool] setFrame:modeFrame];
    }
}
```

Edit:

Please keep in mind that I need to move certain UI elements from being above or beneath each other to being on the side of relative UI elements. I'm not certain if you can do this using auto layout, and I would prefer to do so programmatically anyways.

Comment: You may think Autolayout is "awful" (I disagree) but it is the recommended way for dealing with dynamic changes to height/width in UIViews.  Autolayout will also be less fragile when dealing with new screen sizes.  Finally, the Autolayout in `Xcode 5.1` is far, far more sophisticated than previous versions as all parameters are now exposed. You should give it another try.

Comment: @RoboticCat I'm pretty sure auto layout will not work for what I'm trying to accomplish. I have UI elements that need to move from being below one UI element to being on the side of that UI element. They aren't just moving a little ways up or down.

Comment: Yes - I understand - I've had that issue myself and resorted to completely different view controllers for landscape.  But keep in mind you can create and remove constraints in code so you can swap between a landscape and portrait layout at will (and parameterise those layouts). For example, you could be changing the `constant:` parameter in the `NSLayoutConstraint` method `constraintWithItem:attribute:relatedBy:toItem:attribute:multiplier:constant:`

Answer (score 2):

The proper way to deal with views moving around resizing (or orientation changing) parent views is to use auto layout. It will save you a lot of hassle once you begin using it. Take a look at the documentation here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried using auto layout. It's limited and will not work for what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: Auto layout is complex but it should work - you can set up constraints in code and in IB. The code-based constraints can offer added flexibility if you need it.

Comment: I need to be able to move UI elements from being under different UI elements to being on the side of those UI elements. Can you do this with auto layout? If so, why shouldn't I be able to do it the way I'm trying? In my opinion, doing some simple geometry is easier than trying to use auto layout.

Comment: I would suggest then to step through the code you have, in the debugger, really looking closely at the rectangles being generated and also whatever someRelativeInt is. Yes, it should work fine without auto-layout.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. All I had to do was disable auto layout for that view. To do this I selected the view controller in the storyboard, selected the file inspector, and unchecked "Use Auto Layout" under "Interface Builder Options".